# Creating a project in Team Foundation Server without publishing to SharePoint Server

Tags: tfs, installation

Is it possible to create a project in Team Foundation Server without having TFS wanting it to publish to a SharePoint site? We do have SharePoint Server, but due to unavailibility of our network administrator (hence cannot get rights right now), it is stopping us from exploring any further TFS features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call VersionControlServer.CreateTeamProjectFolder()

Caveats:

- you'll also be missing Work Items, Builds, Reports, etc -- not just the Sharepoint site
- you cannot delete this folder via any public API, unless you first "upgrade" it by running the standard New Team Project wizard (tip: uncheck *create source control folder* on the last page)

In my opinion, unless you are only interested in evaluating the source control features, it would be easier to install TFS on a machine or VM where you have admin rights.  Then migrate the databases to the production server once your domain admins have enough free time to help you.

For what it's worth, TFS 2010 team projects are much more customizable.  Not sure if omitting Sharepoint is possible in Beta 1 yet; definitely will be by the time they release. *Edit* - this configuration is now known as [TFS Basic](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2009/10/21/what-features-are-in-tfs-basic-2010.aspx).

Comment: Richard, thank you for this insight. For our research, we definetly need Work items, builds and reports. This make's it clear that we are better of waiting.

Comment: For some reason, I clicked on upvote, SO ended up downvoting your answer. According to the message poping up, if the answer is edited it should allow me to upvote again.

Comment: Done.  (added a bit more content now that TFS Basic is public knowledge)

Comment: Thanks Richard. I was able to up vote the answer but can only take it back to a zero obviously. Sorry, feel bad about the whole thing.